# Is "attentioned" a word?

Tags: is-it-a-word, correspondence

I am often getting things sent to myself and other people. Is it wrong to say:

> Please send to... [address] attentioned to [name]

I often say:

> Please sent to... [address] and attention it to [name]

On the other hand, I might receive something and it is not mine so I ask a group:

> There's a package here, attentioned to [name]

I guess in the first instance, it should simply be "attention":

> Please send to... [address] attention to [name]

Can you say the last one? "Attention to [name]"?

Comment: I hope it isn't.

Comment: Thanks for your first contribution. Also consider using English Language Learners Stack Exchange for questions about learning English.

Comment: Ha! Thanks, M. K. Hunter. As a side note, I got a suggested edit from *to myself and other people* to **to myself for other people**. However, I did not mean for other people. I actually meant, and. I am getting things sent to other people, from myself. I am also getting things sent to myself, from other people.

Comment: Ah, yes, then "and" will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Attentioned" is not a word. "Attention" is a noun, not a verb. You should say:

> Send it to [me], to the attention of [my friend staying with me]

For example:

> Send it to MKH, to the attention of C.S. Lewis.

Or in a business context

> Send it to headquarters, to the attention of the Payroll Department.

Comment: One of the beautiful things about the English language is that just about _any_ word, especially nouns, can be verbed at will.

Comment: I will upvote your comment out of goodwill, despite "verb" being a noun.

Comment: Precisely the point. See also [this very topical XKCD](http://xkcd.com/1443/).

Comment: If someone says "Attention the letter to me", I concede, I will comprehend it... after translating it out of slang.

Comment: Yes, "to the attention of" is a better way. I probably haven't been listening very well but I often thought people said "attentioned to [name]" or "it's attentioned to [name]".

Answer (score 1):

I'd call this a neologism, and it most likely will be mainstreem sooner or later.

Verbification, or simply verbing, of nouns (and more generally, converting an existing word to a different word class) is an important part of language evolution.

For reference I used:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_%28word_formation%29 and memories of a wild discussion on word conversion in a Swedish class in high school (those were the days...)